# SQL - referring to a 'FROM' subquery column

Tags: sql, subquery

Take this code for example, which selects the highest amount of orders every year:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT year(OrderDate) AS y, month(OrderDate) AS m, 
          count(orderID) ccc,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY count(orderID) DESC) AS rn
    FROM Orders o
    group by year(OrderDate), month(OrderDate)
    ) oo
WHERE oo.rn = 1
```

I don't understand how [WHERE oo.rn = 1] works.

Because, logically, the column rn(row number) refers to a column in the table with the alias 'o' (in the subquery) and not the table with the alias 'oo' (in the general query).

In my logical opinion it should have been [WHERE o.rn = 1]

Comment: `oo` is the `alias` given to the sub query. If you were to use `o.rn`  you would get an error; you actually don't need to use it at all, `where rn=1` would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, the result of a query can be thought of as a table in its own right.

You can "refer" to the result of a query and treat it as such, and when doing so it's known as a *derived table* - ie, it's a table *derived* from the output of another query.

In your example, `SELECT year(OrderDate)...` is a query and the `select *`  is using its results. A rule of the syntax is that a derived table must be given an `alias` by which it can be referred to, the alias in this case is `oo`, which can be used to refer to any column that's part of the inner queries' results.

Because there are no other "tables" referenced in the top level, the query is essentially saying `select * from table`, using the alias is not required and by not using `oo.` the query parser knows it must refer to the only derived table that exists, so `where rn=1` would work just as it would if you were selecting * from an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

AT explain this more clearly, let's store all of that sub-table (The one beginning with `SELECT year(OrderDate)....`) as a variable called z. z is now a table you have created from that select table statement inside the brackets.

The query now looks like SELECT * FROM (z) oo WHERE oo.rn =1
After the brackets you have a statement 'oo' that stores the table returned *inside* the brackets as `oo`.

You then select values from this `oo` table by it's `rn` value